# Filter Row 1 & Sum Values in Row 2 Offset 2 Col Right

Tags: offset, rowfilter

**Google Sheets formula required**
I have a table of 60 rows. Each 4 rows represents 1 mini data table.

2 requirements:
a) In each 4 rows I need to filter for multiple value "LENS", "SCREEN", "VIEW", in Row3 and SUM the values in Row4 below 2 columns to the right of each match.

b) I need to run the same over the entire table to find the sum of all matches through each mini data table.

How do I achieve these 2 things?

I have been searching for an answer to this but have not been able to find a solution that works yet.